# Example of a measurable function satisfying some growth conditions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Let $1<p<\infty$, $A=A(x,s,y):\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be measurable in. $x$ and continuous in $(s,y)$ such that
$$
|A(x,s,y)|\leq c|y|^{p-1},\quad A(x,s,y)\cdot y\geq d|y|^p
$$
for every $(s,y)$ and for a.e. $x$
and
$$
(A(x,s,y_1)-A(x,s,y_2))(y_1-y_2)>0,\quad (A(x,s_1,y)-A(x,s_2,y))(y_1-y_2)\geq 0
$$
for every $y$ and for every $y_1\neq y_2$ and $s_1\neq s_2$.

I can such an assumptions are satisfied if we choose $A(x,s,y)=|y|^{p-2}y$.

But does there exist some example of $A$ which also depends on the second variable $s$ so that all the above conditions are valid?

If yes, can you please give an example. Thanks.

Comment: How can the final assumption be satisfied if $A$ is independent of $s$? Don’t you have $A(x,s_1,y)-A(x,s_2,y)=0$?

Comment: Thanks. I edited it should be greater or equal.

Comment: And is also in the final assumption should it be $s_1-s_2$ instead of $y_1-y_2$?

Comment: Thanks. It is $y_1-y_2$ as mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such $A$ depending on $s$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose that there exists $x$, $y$, $s_1$, and $s_2$ such that $$A(x,s_1,y)\neq A(x,s_2,y) .$$

By the final condition with $y_1=A(x,s_2,y)$ and $y_2 = A(x,s_1,y)$, we have that $$0\leqslant(A(x,s_1,y)-A(x,s_2,y)) \cdot (y_1-y_2)=- \vert A(x,s_1,y)-A(x,s_2,y) \vert^2<0 .$$

The issue is entirely in the final condition. It is my opinion (with zero context of the actual problem so take this with a grain of salt) that this condition should be $$ (A(x,s_1,y)-A(x,s_2,y)) \cdot (s_1-s_2) \geqslant 0$$ (as suggested by my question in the comments).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will see if this condition can be improved to what you are saying.